# New to Google Apps Script - struggling with Gmail.App.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I've tried everything but the cc's and bcc's don't go. I've defined them as variables as in:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1pBTSHr3ExPr_tHlm1WuyVvqFcmcH0cWow8AilC690SU');
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, message,{
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    name:name,
    cc:wardCouncillors,
    cc:tOfficerEmail,
    cc:consOfficerEmail,
    cc:additionalCcs,
    bcc:planningGroup1,
    bcc:planningGroup2,
    
    
  } );
```

The cc's and bcc's have been defined as variables earlier. If I manually type in an email address a cc or bcc will go. The emails themselves are held in a Google Sheet and will vary dependent on the case in question.

Maybe there's a simple explanation but any help would be welcomed.

Thanks.

Andrew

Comment: remove the last , before closing object

Answer (score 1):

```
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, message,{
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    name:name,
    cc: wardCouncillors + "," + tOfficerEmail + "," + consOfficerEmail + "," + additionalCcs + "," + planningGroup1 + "," + planningGroup2} );
```

Comment: Thanks. That's correct but unfortunately that won't solve the problem. I realised that there was that stray comma there after I had sent it. There were two additional 'hard coded' email addresses after that: cc:xx@ycom which I removed when posting as it contains private information, which was why there was a comma after planningGroup2.

Comment: sorry mixed your reply up with that of Waxim Corp. Will try your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Waxim Corp. See my earlier reply to Cooper. I mixed up the responders.

Comment: Thanks so much. You are a lifesaver. That has solved my problem. Very much appreciated.